# How to set value to json object by condition?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a list object returned from server,
example:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "role": "SYSTEM_ADMIN"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "role": "SYSTEM"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "role": "USER"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem here is that I want to set the rank value of each object in the above json follow the condition:

- SYSTEM_ADMIN => rank: 3
- SYSTEM => rank: 2
- USER => rank 1

example:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "role": "SYSTEM_ADMIN",
            "rank": 3
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "role": "SYSTEM",
            "rank": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "role": "USER",
            "rank": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "role": "SYSTEM",
            "rank": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I use javascript quickly set rank values ​​for the object without if else too much? thanks everyone

Comment: have you tried anything? what does not work?

Comment: Just include it in your servers response.

Comment: You should implement this logic on the server side where the json response is being created

Comment: I wrote the code and worked with me but too much if else, I want to find a refactor or a better solution

Comment: whats the problem with too many if else? do you have a problem with readable code? :|

Comment: yes, code too long and many logic, i want to refactor it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some people suggested, it's best to do it on the server when you create the response.

If you still need to do it on the frontend for some reason, you can create a constant map that stores each role value's rank in an object map:

```js
const rankMap = {
  SYSTEM_ADMIN: 3,
  SYSTEM: 2,
  USER: 1
};

const data = {
  "items": [{
      "id": 1,
      "role": "SYSTEM_ADMIN"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "role": "SYSTEM"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "role": "USER"
    }
  ]
}

data.items = data.items.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  rank: rankMap[item.role],
}));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: I still suggest you to do this on the server side. also, could you accept the answer if it answered your question?

Comment: I handing on UI because the rank is only used to calculate whether or not to delete based on the canDelete field, I will add a canDelete field if the current login user's rank is greater than the object's rank in the returned list. example: I have logged in with a user role System_admin =>

Comment: {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "role": "SYSTEM_ADMIN",
            "rank": 3,
            "canDelete": "false"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "role": "SYSTEM",
            "rank": 2,
            "canDelete": "true"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "role": "USER",
            "rank": 1,
            "canDelete": "true"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "role": "SYSTEM",
            "rank": 2,
            "canDelete": "true"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object which contains `rank` and then just use `map`:

```
let ranks = {SYSTEM_ADMIN: 3, SYSTEM: 2, USER: 1};
let result = items.map(({id, role})=> ({id, role, rank: ranks[role]}));
```

An example:

```js
let items = [
  {
      "id": 1,
      "role": "SYSTEM_ADMIN"
  },
  {
      "id": 2,
      "role": "SYSTEM"
  },
  {
      "id": 3,
      "role": "USER"
  }
];

let ranks = {SYSTEM_ADMIN: 3, SYSTEM: 2, USER: 1};

let result = items.map(({id, role})=> ({id, role, rank: ranks[role]}));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: how i append filed can delete based rank? condition: If rank on list object less than current rank, canDelete is true, else false? i working on this but too much code logic if else

Comment: @VănNguyễnDuy could you write examples? With source data and desired data as text? It will help to understand what is desirable

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a list of the roles and their respective ranks in a dictionary. The response can then very simply be mapped

```js
let response = {
    items: [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "role": "SYSTEM_ADMIN",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "role": "SYSTEM",
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "role": "USER",
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "role": "SYSTEM",
        }
    ]
}

let rankMap = {
    "SYSTEM_ADMIN": 3,
    "SYSTEM": 2,
    "USER": 1
}

response.items.forEach(i => i['rank'] = rankMap[i.role]);

console.log(response);
```